# Error in java executable file in cmd

Tags: java, netbeans

I have develop an application in java netbeans and want to run it with:

```
java -jar MyFile.jar
```

When I run my application at the command prompt, it is showing an error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/netbeans/lib/awtextra/AbsoluteLayout
```

I set the layout of panel as absolute that's why it is showing this error. How can I remove this error to run my application successfully?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteLayout` to the classpath. Given you are running from a JAR, you need to edit the JAR manifest - see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/downman.html

You will also need to add other dependent classes, of course.